# How can I select multiple rows in UITableView

Tags: uitableview, selection

I want to display some selected contacts in a list and then I need a feature to select multiple contacts at a time and  then on clicking a button it should trigger an email to the selected contacts.

For this I am using UITableView to display the contacts but I  am not able to find any way to unable the multiple selection for UITableView. On doing some google search I found that UITableView does not support multiple selection.

Is there any way to select multiple rows in UITableView or which control should I use for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cellAccessorytype` for selecting a row when finished with the selection.  Just check which cell has accessory mark, put that content into the array and use them.